# How to divide values in SQL statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such statement in attachment and can anybody help me.

I need to divide the value of " CountUnSuccess" to "Count" and show that result in a statement.
Could you please help, what I need to add in the statement in order that happens?

Thank you

[image: SQL Statement Image]

Comment: Have you tried division operator `/`?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of pictures.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(P2._total)/NULLIF(COUNT(p1.total)/100.0, 0.0) AS div
```

Alternatively

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(P2._total)*100.0/NULLIF(COUNT(p1.total), 0.0) AS div
```

Comment: @Andris Smits: Then, maybe you should select it as answer ;)